# Differential integrator vs standard

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, instrumentation-amplifier, integrator, miller-integrator

I want to integrate/amplify a very small signal (relatively short pulses of 100ns to 4ms, necessitate high-bandwidth components minimum 40MHz+). The capacitors will be switched (shorted) when not in use, and unshorted at the right moment to integrate a pulse (finite time).

I wonder if there's any benefits to use a differential integrator topology like this (or on the contrary if it's not more error prone in the presence of mismatches):

[image]

Or integrate the differential signal directly using a single capacitor op-amp integrator like this:

[image]

Is it bad practice to use analog differential integrators considering capacitor mismatches are very likely to happen, even with C0G for example (tolerance +/- 1%)? Are there products on the market (for example "matched" capacitors) to overcome this potential issue?
Since an integrator output depends on time, I suppose the mismatch error will only grow as time goes by.

Yet, I suppose this topology (dual capacitors diff.) has some advantages since it is somewhat common.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: I'd use your 2nd circuit; more conventional and reliable.